# Error: Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_MyModule_Block_Classname

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I'm getting an exception in my log which says:

```
Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_MyModuleName_Block_Classname in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Mage_MyMod...', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('mymodulena...', 'mymodulena...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('mymodulena...', 'mymodulena...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

I'm guessing magento cant find the block:

```
Mage_MyModuleName_Block_Classname
```

Because it's supposed to be:

```
MyNameSpace_MyModuleName_Block_Classname
```

As you can see in the log, i'm calling a layout. this is(?) part of the error. I've come to the conclusion that there's something wrong in one of these xml files:

**(layout.xml) path to mymodulename.xml:**

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodulename.xml
```

mymodulename.xml:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <block 
        type="myModuleName/Classname" 
        name="mymodulename.list" 
        template="mymodulename/list.phtml">
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**(config.xml) path to my module's config.xml:**

```
app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModuleName/etc/config.xml
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNameSpace_MyModuleName>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyNameSpace_MyModuleName>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodulename>
                    <file>mymodulename.xml</file>
                </mymodulename>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mynamespace_mymodulename>
                <class>MyNameSpace_MyModuleName_Helper</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodulename>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <mynamespace_mymodulename>
                <class>MyNameSpace_MyModuleName_Block</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodulename>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <mynamespace_mymodulename>
                <class>MyNameSpace_MyModuleName_Model</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodulename>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I made sure I exactly copied the letter casing of the placeholders (MyModuleName & MyNameSpace). Tell me if you need more info.

Comment: Have you declared your module in etc/modules?

Comment: yes, it's enabled in System > Config > Advanced

Comment: Is that your complete Config.xml? Where is the block node?

Comment: Can you post the full config.xml for your module. The first part of the block type before the forward slash should match the name you gave your block in the config.xml

Comment: i have added the full config.xml